# Help understanding "to have" in sentences like "I would have liked to have invited few people."

Tags: verbs, auxiliary-verbs, subjunctives

Yes, I am still confused with the sentences like ' to have' but not all the sentences related 'to have'. I can understand the sentences below:

> I am happy to have been invited by him.
>
> He was happy to have met Mr. Smith.
>
> He was supposed to have married on 20 December.
>
> You have to have made a reservation.
>
> He must have been  driven to despair to have killed her.

But I do not understand the sentences like:

> It is considered normal for the people these days to have had some practical knowledge before joining some  a new job.
>
> It is better to have loved & lost than never to have lost at all.
>
> I would have liked to have invited few people.
>
> It would have been nice to have had great Bollywood presence. The most popular symbol of India.

Comment: ...than never to have *loved* at all.

Comment: What exactly about them don't you understand?  All of them are the present perfect, *have + past-participle*: have been, have met, have had, have loved, have invited, etc.

Comment: You are confusing tenses (present perfect) and its use in a broader phrase.

Comment: The last example contains one sentence and one sentence fragment. `The most popular symbol of India.` is not a complete sentence.

Answer (score 1):

> I would have liked **to have invited** few people.

*to [verb]* is an [infinitive](http://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/infinitive/) form.

*have invited* is the [present perfect](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfect.html) tense of *invite*.

A sentence with a similar meaning would be..

> I wanted to invite few people.

I'll also highlight the verbs of the rest of your examples:

> It is considered normal for the people these days **to have had** some practical knowledge before joining some a new job.
>
> It would have been nice **to have had** great Bollywood presence. The most popular symbol of India.

*have had* is the present perfect tense of *have*.

> It is better **to have loved** & **[to have] lost** than never to have loved at all.

These are the present perfect tenses of *love* and *lost*.

Comment: I know these are the present perfect tenses but what are the meanings of them.

Comment: to have invited **a** few people...

Answer (score 1):

*To have [pp]* is simply the **past infinitive**.

Despite what people have said in other answers, it is not necessarily semantically "perfect": though it resembles the present perfect in syntax, it is simply past in meaning.

So

> I'm happy **to be invited** by him.

- non-past (present or future)

> I'm happy **to have been invited** by him.

- past.

*I would have liked to have invited few people.* = *I would have liked to (be somebody who) invited a few people.* (Note the word "invited" in the paraphrase is a simply past, not the past participle of the original sentence. They just happen to have the same form).

Answer (score 0):

Imo both sets of sentences, fall in the category of the subject being in a state, or wanting to be in s state.

Let's explain using a sentence that you understand and one that you are confused about:

> [I am happy] to [have been invited by him.]

I have been invited (by him). That's my [state]
I am happy to be in this state.

hence,
I am happy to [have been invited by him]

> [I would have liked] to [have invited few people.]

I did not invite few people.
The [state] here is the state of [having invited few people.]
I would have liked to be in that state.

hence,
I would have liked to [have invited few people]

I hope this clears the intuition of these 2 sentences.